# debugging odd slowness in the application throughput

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am facing a problem, where running the same application on different servers, yields unexpected throughput results. For example, running the application on a particular faster server (faster cpu, more memory), with no load, yields slower throughput than running on a less powerful server on the same network.

I am suspecting that either OS or TCP is causing the slowness on the faster server. 
Is there a tool that can look at OS and TCP configuration and suggest the cause of slowness?

All the servers are running Red hat linux.

UPDATE
It is a socket based client server application. It works with single connection, such as single client connected to the server, trying to send messages as fast as possible. No forking or multi threading.

On further thought, Are there key tcp options that can impact either latency or throughput?

Comment: Give more context, what kind of app ? Socket app / web app / forking / threading etc.

Answer (score 0):

The key to debugging issues like this is to remove the physical network from the test cases; in other words compare tcp application transfers through localhost instead of through the network.

In most cases, the NIC configuration, bonding config, end to end TCP RTT, packet reordering, packet loss rates, or other external factors are to blame for these kind of differences.  To determine whether it is "the network" or the server, test from localhost to localhost.